# Macro to copy, rename and organize a template worksheet

Tags: copy, rename

I am trying to write a macro to copy the "Template" worksheet, rename it with user input, and save it in either alphabetical order or numerical order.

I am also trying to figure out how to include user input in 4 of the cells within the template sheet.

Nothing that has worked at all.